# Error: Invalid version main specified in PGCLUSTER (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, psql

input: `root@Tactical-TUF:/mnt/d/vscode/# psql`
output: `Error: Invalid version main specified in PGCLUSTER`

Basically no `psql` commands are working.
I tried every sources but i just couldnt find the right solution for it and i keep getting the same error everytime. Im on **WSL** terminal in VS Code.

How can i run `psql -p 5432` to enter inside the new connection?

Answer (score -1):

this error is because of issue with pgluster configuration or initialization. ostgresql. So for running psql on 5432 port and entering into the new connection, you have to do the following.
frist make sure that the cluster which you want to enter is online, for this check all the current clusters using this command.

```
pg_lsclusters
```

Now specify the database name and its user name

```
psql -d mydatabase -U myuser
```

Now check that the configuration files for PostgreSQL at /etc/postgresql/version>/main/ are accurate.

Recreate the cluster using pg_createcluster if problems continue.

```
sudo pg_createcluster 13 main --start
```

Make sure that there are no conflicting environment variables set, particularly PGCLUSTER.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I recreated the cluster, but now all my tables are gone... What do I do now?

Comment: Have you created a backup of your database using pg_dump ?

Comment: No, I have not...

Comment: Oops.. By the way there is one more solution, pstgreSQL normally makes a backup of the data directory at a location like /var/lib/postgresql/version>/main/pgdata.bak before re-creating the cluster. You can try to restore your data from a backup of this directory if you have one.